# I set up a an apache2 virtualhost but now I cant seem to access my /etc/var/www/ files?

Tags: server, apache2, virtualhost

I think this is due to me pointing my `/etc/hosts` file to `127.0.0.1 mysite.com` But there isnt really another way of pointing my virtual host to the localhost?

My host file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   felix
127.0.0.1   mysite.com
```

Inside `/var/www/` I made a file:

```
info.php

<php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

But when I try to reach this by doing `localhost/info.php` I get a 404 not found error.

What can be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Apache usually ships with a default virtualhost with a document root set to `/var/www/html/`.

To see what virtualhosts your server currently has configured, run `apache2ctl -S`, then either move your files to the document root you see, or create a new virtuahost container that uses the document root you want.

Comment: Yeah I know. And I still have that as my root. But the problem is that I overwrite 127.0.0.1 with my virtual host. Is there a way to fix this? (To still run a virtual host locally)